# REDHAT VM to run as HOST

Tags: linux, virtualization, redhat, virtual-machines, lvm

I'm running a RHEL5 w/ 1 VM, that VM runs it's own LVM (boot, swap and root).

so now what I need is to be able to boot directly into that VM bypassing my host enviroment and making my VM is a host, I figured since it's has it's own LVM i should be able to load it up directly.

VM itself is a RHEL5 and currently host runs RHEL5 w/ XEN VM

Comment: Please make this readable english. I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I think he's got a RHEL5 hosting a VM of some kind.  He wants to boot the VM install directly on the hardware without bothering with the RHEL5 host (ie a non-VM install).  But without knowing more about the setup, I couldn't answer the question.

Comment: What is the VM's operating system?  When you sah "has its own LVM", is that on a real disk or a virtual one?  VMware or Xen (since I'm presuming KVM in RHEL 5 is too new for anyone to have actually deployed it yet)?

Comment: i just rephrase it, i hope this is better

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood you correctly, you want the *HOST* to not boot, and only the *HOSTED* VM to boot?

That's not possible without doing a V2P migration. The hypervisor has to be running, or the VM cannot.

Comment: What's V2P? and what's Hypervisor? XEN can be fully virtualized and/or PARA virtualized, fully virtualized it's like you running full blown OS without any modifications, para is slightly modified OS

Comment: @alexus, I thought you'd know :) ..The "hypervisor" is the virtualization engine you're running. "V2P" is the shorthand for "virtual to physical".

Comment: Warren is correct. The host OS must be running since that is where the hypervisor lives. If you want a small footprint host try VMWare ESXi.

Answer (score 0):

Are you attempting to move your VM out of the virtual environment onto the parent physical server?

If so, it's possible cloning software like [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) may do this.  Boot Clonezilla inside the VM, clone the virtual disk to a network attached storage device (or something else) outside the VM, then boot Clonezilla on the physical machine and clone that image down to the bare metal.

Somebody correct me if this won't work!

Comment: It will only work if the real hardware is close enough to the VM's hardware that the "VM" can boot on the bare metal.  If the bare metal requires some fancy ethernet or RAID controller driver, you might not get anywhere.

Comment: in Linux - quite possible actually

Comment: my hardware close enough, at least i'd like to think so and I want to give it a shot...

Comment: backup, backup, backup before trying!